# launch.json file for JavaFX is not working in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I am running jdk17 with JavaFX sdk 17.0.9;
I am trying to use JavaFX, and I have added my JAR files to the preferences, and I have also added this.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "${file}"
    }
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "App",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "App",
        "projectName": "testfx_1e12e64c"
        "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-17.0.9\" --add-modules javafx.controls\\,javafx.fxml",
    }
]
}
```

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
     @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("testfx.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
     }
}
```

I have tried moving my JavaFX folder to a place that does not contain spaces. I have also experimented with jdk 21 as well.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode, https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/VSCode/Non-Modular/Java/hellofx/.vscode/launch.json

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for JavaFX and VS Code are in getting started at openjfx.io.

- [Getting Started with JavaFX: JavaFX and Visual Studio Code.](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode)

Your `--module-path` is wrong. It should be:

```
--module-path \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-17.0.9\\lib\"
```

Note the addition of the JavaFX SDK `lib` directory to the path.  That is where the JavaFX modules actually are.

Also, I don't think `--add-modules` needs slashes in it.  I am not sure about that as the openjfx.io setup example is for a non-windows based example which may have different escape rules, but I think, for this one, you don't need to escape the comma, even on Windows.  I think the `--add-modules` argument should be:

```
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

[Example setup at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/images/ide/vscode/ide/vscode07.png) unfortunately as an image ;-)

[image]

But also I retyped it here as text, and it is also [available in the openjfx samples repository](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/VSCode/Non-Modular/Java/hellofx/.vscode/launch.json):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Launch App",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "hellofx.Main",
      "vmArgs": "--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
    }
  ]
}
```

The example is from openjfx.io for a non-Windows style path, so if on Windows you need to adopt the path with escaping similar to the earlier examples in this answer.